# calling a quick sort function with the comparison function as a parameter

Tags: c, sorting, function-pointers

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm having trouble with understanding pointers thoroughly. In my program below, in the main method, I'm just wondering what the right way to test my Qsort function is. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void swap(void *v[], int i, int j)
{
    void *temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j]=temp;
}

int cmp1 (void *first_arg,  void *second_arg)
{
    int first = *(int *)first_arg;
    int second = *(int *)second_arg;
    if ( first < second )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( first == second )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int cmp2  (void * a, void * b)
{
    return ( *(int *)a - *(int *)b );
}


void cmp3 (void *a, void *b)
{
    char one = *(char *)a;
    char two = *(char *)b;

    if (one == two){
        printf("The two values are equal");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The two values are not equal");
    }

}

void QSort(void *v[],int left, int right, int (*compare)(void *first, void *second))
{
    int i, last;
    void swap (void *v[],int ,int);


    if(left >= right){
        return;
    }

    swap(v,left,(left+right)/2);
    last=left;
    for(i=left+1;i<=right; i++){
        if((*compare)(v[i],v[left])<0){
            swap(v,++last,i);
        }
    }

    swap(v,left,last);
    QSort(v,left,last-1,compare);
    QSort(v,last+1,right,compare);
}




int main()
{
    int first = 23;
    int second = 4;
    int third = 5;
    int temp[3];//={22,4,36,64,0};

    temp[0] = (void *)&first;
    temp[1]=(void *)&second;
    temp[2]=(void *)&third;

    QSort(temp, 0, 2, cmp1(.....));

    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        printf("%d ",*((int *)temp[n]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int temp[3]`, then assigning `int*` to each element, and you *didn't* get at least a warning out of that compiler?

Comment: Make sure to paste valid code. `QSort(temp, 0, 2, cmp1(.....));` is *not* what you are using.

Comment: Now, to give the question *direction*: What is the *actual* problem that is occurring? Is there a syntax error? Is the result not sorted correctly (by which compare function)? Does the program crash?

Comment: What are you actually *hoping* for, because this is *not* how one should setup sorting a sequence of values. the only comparator that stands any chance of reasonable success is `cmp1`, but I sincerely question what the intent and motivation are for why you setup QSort the way you did. If you want a generic QSort, you could/should model it after [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). An array of `void*`, especially improperly sent an array of int` improperly loaded with `int*`, isn't the way to do that.

Comment: people usually use typedefs with function pointers because they are quite obscure to read

Comment: I thought this was a good question, reading `cmp1` and `cmp2` ... then I hit `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp1` is really the best way.  It should always perform correctly.

`cmp2` is close.  It would work most of the time, but if you are dealing with very large integers, the results would be wrong.

`cmp3` is definitely not right.  The values are actually `int`s, but are being treated as `char`s.  The results would be meaningless.

Comment: `cmp2` is undefined behaviour in many cases, e.g. if you end up doing `INT_MIN - 1`. Even if that operation does a "wrap-around", I don't think it constitutes a stable sort (so the sort may not complete successfully)

Answer (score 1):

```
QSort(temp, 0, 2, cmp1(.....));
```

shoud be

```
QSort(temp, 0, 2, cmp1);
```

If `foo` is name of a function, then you use `foo()` to call it, and use `foo` to pass it as an argument to another function that requires a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

temp is not an integer array, it should be array of integer pointers.

line

```
   int temp[3];
```

should be replaced with

```
   int *temp[3];
```

Comment: Should be `void *temp[3];` actually